# Possibility of Dynamic Data with EAV

Tags: asp.net, entity-attribute-value

I will be defining my entities to have a dynamic schema using the EAV pattern wherein I can define attributes in a AttributeMaster table and Entities in an EntityMaster table with a Many-Many relationship among them.

What does it take to create a Dynamic Data application which uses the EAV structure as metadata and save the values in the EAV model?
Is this even possible? Any frameworks in place?

Thanks,
Yash

Comment: See [Five Simple Database Design Errors You Should Avoid (point 3)](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/five-simple--database-design-errors-you-should-avoid/) and maybe rethink your architecture....

Comment: We are building an Ecommerce application where the attributes of products is not known in advance.

Comment: Read another article: [Bad CaRMa](http://www.simple-talk.com/content/article.aspx?article=292) - just don't do it - it'll fail, with almost 100% certainty ....